# Sequelize - SQL Server - order by for association tables

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables such as `user`, `userProfile` and `userProfileImages`. `User` is mapping with `userPrfoile` as has many and `userProfile` is mapping with `userProfileImages` as has many.

I need to write the **order by query** in `userProfileImages`, I tried as below, but no luck.

```
User.findById(uID, { 
include: [
   model: sequelize.models.userProfile
   as: userProfile,
   include: [
    {
      model: sequelize.models.userProfileImages,
      as: 'profileImages',

    }
   ],
    order: [[sequelize.models.userProfileImages.id, "desc"]]
  // order: [["id", "desc"]] --> Tried this way also no luck
] }
```

I am getting the result, but `userProfilePicture` table's result is not as desc.

Kindly give the solutions

Comment: please try with single array and not 2d array like: `["id", "desc"]`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. one more thing, I have done one more mapping also inside the 2nd include. as

Comment: Order by keyword is not appended in my query also.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From Sequelize offical docs:

```
    // Will order by an associated model's created_at using an association object. (preferred method)
    [Subtask.associations.Task, 'createdAt', 'DESC'],

    // Will order by a nested associated model's created_at using association objects. (preferred method)
    [Subtask.associations.Task, Task.associations.Project, 'createdAt', 'DESC'],
```

By referring above syntax, Update your order option like below

```
User.findById(uID, { 
    include: [{
        model: sequelize.models.userProfile
        as: userProfile,
        include: [{
           model: sequelize.models.userProfileImages,
           as: 'profileImages',
        }],
        order: [['profileImages','id', 'desc']]
    }]
});
```

Official Documentations: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#ordering

Refer this thread for more solutions: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553

Comment: finally something that works :), thx buddy.

Comment: I'm using Sequelize 6.7.0 and with that code I get: "Error: Unknown structure passed to order / group: NAME_OF_ALIAS"

Answer (score 14):

Update your order in association like below

```
User.findById(uID, { 
include: [
    model: sequelize.models.userProfile,
    as: userProfile,        
    include: [{
       model: sequelize.models.userProfileImages,
       as: 'profileImages',
       separate:true, <-- Magic here
       order: [['id', 'desc']]
    }],
]});
```

Comment: This worked. Adding the `separate` tag and setting it to `true` did the trick for me.

Comment: Only HasMany associations support include.separate.

Answer (score -1):

```
User.findById(uID, { 
subQuery : false , 
include: [
    model: sequelize.models.userProfile,
    as: userProfile,        
    include: [{
       model: sequelize.models.userProfileImages,
       as: 'profileImages',
       separate:true, <-- Magic here
       order: [['id', 'desc']]
    }],
]});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.