# How to convert a sql join query to sequelizejs query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am having trouble in a query which works fine in MuSQL workbench as

```
SELECT * 
FROM coupons 
    LEFT JOIN coupon_activities ON coupons.coupon=coupon_activities.coupon 
ORDER BY coupon_activities.best_discount = true DESC, 
        coupon_activities.worked = true DESC, 
        coupons.expire_date DESC;
```

But in Node.js using sequelizejs i am having trouble.

This is the Model of coupons table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let coupon = sequelize.define("coupon", {
        merchant_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        domain: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        coupon: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        expire_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        }
    }, {
            indexes: [{ fields: ['merchant_id'] }],
            createdAt: false,
            updatedAt: false,
            tableName: 'coupons',
        });

    return coupon;
};
```

And this is the coupons_activity model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let couponActivity = sequelize.define("coupon_activity", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true
    },
    coupon: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    merchant_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    application_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    },
    worked: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    best_discount: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    discount_amount: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: true
    },
  }, {
    indexes: [{ fields: ['merchant_id'] }],
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    tableName: 'coupon_activities',
  });

  return couponActivity;
};
```

Added a association

```
models.coupon.hasMany(models.coupon_activity, { as: 'Activity', foreignKey: 'merchant_id' });
```

This is what i am doing in the function

```
try {
    const coupons = await models.coupon.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.coupon_activity,
            as: 'Activity'
        }]
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ response: "Error in server" });
}
```

I am getting all the data from another table foreach record like that

```
 "coupons": [
    {
        "merchant_id": 19,
        "domain": "newegg.com",
        "coupon": "22WCPC101",
        "description": "$61.99 after savings. Plus, free shipping. ",
        "expire_date": "2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Activity": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "coupon": "22WCPC101",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-03-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": false,
                "best_discount": false,
                "discount_amount": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "coupon": "353GAL34",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-03-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": true,
                "best_discount": true,
                "discount_amount": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "coupon": "EMCSTWTA2",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-03-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": true,
                "best_discount": false,
                "discount_amount": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "coupon": "BCPTAKE10",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-02-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": false,
                "best_discount": false,
                "discount_amount": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "coupon": "AFM2SSD26",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-03-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": false,
                "best_discount": false,
                "discount_amount": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "coupon": "EXTRATENOFF",
                "merchant_id": "19",
                "application_date": "2019-02-14T05:25:03.000Z",
                "worked": false,
                "best_discount": false,
                "discount_amount": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

But what i want is to only get the data which matches the coupon code of both. And then need to sort it.

Comment: So remove `LEFT` from your join? Also `ORDER BY x =true` is redundant, just `ORDER BY x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your association uses 'merchant_id':

```
models.coupon.hasMany(models.coupon_activity, { as: 'Activity', foreignKey: 'merchant_id' });
```

but it should use 'coupon' if you want

```
..coupons LEFT JOIN coupon_activities ON coupons.coupon=coupon_activities.coupon ...
```

FWIW, many Sequelize problems can be resolved by examining the generated SQL in the server log.

Comment: I have also tried coupons instead of  merchant_id but as is schema there are two primary keys so sequelize always picks the 1st one from the 1st table and i am getting no results

Comment: That's a different story.  Making Sequelize join on two fields is (IMHO) has been a hassle for a while (see [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311) but you may be able to get it working using scopes.  Try this association: `models.coupon.hasMany(models.coupon_activity, { as: 'Activity', foreignKey: 'merchant_id', scope: {coupon : { $col : 'coupon.coupon' }}});`
this should change your SQL to ...`coupon JOIN coupon_activity ON coupon.merchant_id = coupon_activity.merchant_id AND coupon.coupon = coupon_activity.coupon`  The only problem is, it leaves some junk in the JSON...

Comment: Do you know how to order by this query like this ORDER BY coupon_activities.best_discount = true DESC,  coupon_activities.worked = true DESC,  coupons.expire_date DESC; i tried several ways but no luck

Comment: In your case, you'll want to include the associated model in the order clause for the two activity fields, roughly as follows:  `order : [[couponActivity,'worked', 'desc']]`  The manual has some good examples (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027310/sequelize-sql-server-order-by-for-association-tables).