# How can I sort the User depending on Book id?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a User model and a Book model and the relationship is user has one book, book belongs to a user. In this context I want to sort the returned result depending on the book id.

```
return await models.Users.findAll(
    include: [{
        model: models.Book,
    }]
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize - SQL Server - order by for association tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027310/sequelize-sql-server-order-by-for-association-tables)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#ordering

```
await models.Users.findAll(
    include: [{
        model: models.Book,
    }],
    order: [[models.Book, 'id', 'DESC']]
)
```