# how to sort associated tables in sequelze?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to return an associated table, but sort those items. Nothing complicated like sorting *by* an associated table. Just sort the associated elements.

```
    public static async findWith(finder: any): Promise<Race | null> {
        const race = await Race.findOne({
            where: finder,
            include: [
                {
                    model: Rocket,
                    order: ['id', 'desc']
                }
            ]
        })
        return race
    }
```

I tried a few options,

```
order: ['id', 'desc']
order: [['id', 'desc']]
order: [[Rocket, 'id', 'desc']]. // nested
```

which are all accepted without error, but the sorting isn't applied.

research:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553
- https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/
- [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027310/sequelize-sql-server-order-by-for-association-tables)

I'm using sequelize-typescript with v6 and postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in sequelize documentation that if you want to apply ORDER clauses to eager loaded models, you must use the top level order option. Therefore, you should write it outside the include option like this

```js
const race = await Race.findOne({
            where: finder,
            include: [
                {
                    model: Rocket
                }
            ],
            order: [[Rocket, 'id', 'desc']]
        })
```

Comment: interesting, so what if you want to sort different associations differently? eg one by id and one by date? i don't see a way with this to do that.

Comment: Suppose you want to sort Race by 'id' in DESC order and Rocket by 'name' in ASC order. Then the query will be => order: [ [ 'id', 'DESC'], [Rocket, 'name', 'ASC' ] ]